# Not getting output on emulator window

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, ddms

I am a beginner and trying to run Hello world application using developer.android.com.
I am using eclipse helios, Android 2.3, latest jdk and sdk. Using window xp so 32-bit versions are there.
I am unable to get output on emulator window which pop. There is no output either on pane or main screen. 
I am using default ddms.bat and have not make any changes. Can anyone suggest what to do.

My ddms.bat and java code are attached

vishal

ddms.bat

```
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

set jarfile=ddms.jar
set frameworkdir=

if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=lib\

if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\framework\

:JarFileOk

if debug NEQ "%1" goto NoDebug
    set java_debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8050,suspend=y
    shift 1
:NoDebug

set jarpath=%frameworkdir%%jarfile%

if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
    set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
    goto SwtDone

:QueryArch

    for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar %frameworkdir%archquery.jar') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%%%a

:SwtDone

if exist %swt_path% goto SetPath
    echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    exit /B

:SetPath
set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir= -classpath "%jarpath%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.ddms.Main %*
```

Java code

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
        tv.setText("Hello, Android"); 
        setContentView(tv);
        }
}
```

Comment: No need to paste the DMMS. Also... could you be more specific? What do you spec to see? What do you see instead? Does eclipse gives you erros when trying to execute the app? Did you correctly create the android emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this 'problem' the emulator takes a long time to start up. Leave it for 10 mins and the text should appear!

Comment: Dear Cristian, I am expecting "Hello, Android" to come on screen. But nothig comes. There is a default screen with android written. Also on window pane it is written 5554:my_sdk(name of virtual device). Whereas I was expecting helloandroid. I followed the exact hello world procedure. I am seeing emulator window with key board. There was error "bad version : standalone". But after adding ping emulator 0012 on ddms.bat this error goes off. I could not get output in either case.